# Save and increment calls using sharedpreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save the count of missed calls in one activity and read them in another one.
1st activity:

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)
            || intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {




        // get the phone number
        String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

        // This code will execute when the call is disconnected
        Toast.makeText(context, "missed call number " + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        SharedPreferences s = context.getSharedPreferences("s" ,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor e = s.edit();
        int count= s.getInt("counter" , 1);
        e.putInt("counter",count++);
        e.commit();


    }

}
```

The toast in working and i know the number of the caller but i can't save the count and read it in the 2nd activity:

```
SharedPreferences s = getSharedPreferences("s" ,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int calls = s.getInt("counter" , 0 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In below line,

```
    e.putInt("counter", count++); // post increment is error-prone.
```

could be changed to

```
    e.putInt("counter", ++count);
```

Or, just add 1 simply.

```
    e.putInt("counter", count + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the same context while saving and retrieving values. use getApplicationContext().